# Alternative to cloning tokio channel's sender for futures' closures

Tags: concurrency, rust, rust-tokio

I'm working with `tokio` and `hyper` to spawn several tasks.

```
// Defining the task
let task = self.some_future_using
            .map(move |resp| println!("OK: {}", resp))
            .map_err(move |e| println!("Error: {}",e));

// Spawning the task
tokio::spawn(task);
```

Instead of simply logging the results, I would like to send the result over a bounded tokio channel.

```
// Defines the channel
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

// Defining the task
let task = self.some_future_using
            .map(|resp| /* Send Ok(resp) to tx */ )
            .map_err(|e| /* Send Err(e) to tx */);

// Spawning the task
tokio::spawn(task);
```

As both closures may outlive the scope where `tx` is defined, we need to clone and move `tx` for both closures:

```
// Defines the channel
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(10);
let mut tx_ok = tx.clone();
let mut tx_err = tx.clone();

// Defining the task
let task = self.some_future_using
            .map(move |resp| tx_ok.try_send(Ok(())).unwrap() )
            .map_err(move |e| tx_err.try_send(Ok(())).unwrap() );

// Spawning the task
tokio::spawn(task);
```

In the case more logic is added using combinators (`map`, `and_then`, etc), every closures would require it's own cloned version of `tx` to use it.

Is cloning the only solution? Could we achieve the same without cloning the channel's sender for each declared closure that uses it?

Comment: Are you seeing significant overhead with cloning the sender? I would expect this to be a very efficient operation.

Comment: you can avoid one clone in your example. "every closures would require it's own cloned version of tx to use it." => "every closures would require it's own version of tx to use it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could we achieve the same without cloning the channel's sender for each declared closure that uses it?

No. This is how a `Sender` is shared, and there isn't another safe way to do it.

The channel manages shared resources by wrapping them in `Arc`s, so they can be shared safely between threads. There is a bit of logic involved in the `Sender`'s clone method, but ultimately it is about cloning those `Arc`s - which is how `Arc`s are shared.

Cloning an `Arc` is cheap, and probably not something you should worry about, unless you are cloning them in a tight loop. Once they are cloned, there is very little overhead to an `Arc` - each clone is essentially a pointer.

Comment: I was not afraid of performance. It was more a syntax/style oriented question. In the case I would have 10 closures, I wanted to avoid typing clone 10 times.